# How select favorite button when i use a LazyList and mantain the state of favorite button - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working with a LazyList where I want to favorite items and display them. Currently, when I select an item, it gets favorited, but if I change the list's sorting using filters, the selected item remains based on the index of the list, not the selected object. How can I ensure that the selected item persists based on the object, even after changing the sorting of the LazyList?

first time selected items vs. when i select any filter:

[image]
    
[image]

inside a column in my compose function

```
var productList = state.productList
val options = listOf(
    "Menor preço",
    "Maior preço",
    "A-Z",
    "Z-A",
    "Favoritos"
)
var selectedOption by remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
val onSelectionChange = { text: String ->
    selectedOption = text
}
Text(text = "Ordenar por")
Spacer(modifier = Modifier)
Row(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .heightIn(70.dp)
        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    options.forEach { text ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                style = typography.bodySmall.merge(),
                color = OldBurgundy,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            size = 12.dp,
                        ),
                    )
                    .clickable {
                        onSelectionChange(text)
                    }
                    .background(
                        if (text == selectedOption) {
                            DarkCoral
                        } else {
                            DeepPeach
                        }
                    )
                    .padding(
                        vertical = 12.dp,
                        horizontal = 16.dp,
                    ),
            )
        }
    }
}
when (selectedOption) {
    "Menor preço" -> {
        productList = productList?.sortedBy { it.price?.toFloat() }
    }

    "Maior preço" -> {
        productList = productList?.sortedByDescending { it.price?.toFloat() }
    }

    "A-Z" -> {
        productList = productList?.sortedBy { it.brand }
    }

    "Z-A" -> {
        productList = productList?.sortedByDescending { it.brand }
    }

    else -> {}
}
LazyColumn(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
) {
    if (productList != null) {
        for (product in productList) {
            item {
                CardProductItem(product)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fuction compose card item

```
@Composable
fun CardProductItem(
    product: ProductListItem,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    elevation: Dp = 4.dp
) {
    Card(
        modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(100.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = elevation
        )
    ) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(DeepPeach)
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Row {
                Text(text = "Marca: ", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(
                    text = product.brand ?: "marca indisponivel",
                    color = WengeGray
                )
                Spacer(
                    Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .fillMaxHeight())
                FavoriteButton(
                    productIsFavorite = product.isFavorite,
                    onFavoriteClicked = {
                        product.isFavorite = it
                    }
                )
            }
            Row {
                Text(text = "Preço: ", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(
                    text = product.price ?: "preço indisponivel",
                    color = WengeGray
                )
            }
            Row {
                Text(
                    buildAnnotatedString {
                        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)) {
                            append("Descrição: ")
                        }
                        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = WengeGray)) {
                            append(product.description ?: "descrição indisponivel")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

function favorite button

```
@Composable
fun FavoriteButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color(0xffE91E63),
    productIsFavorite: Boolean,
    onFavoriteClicked: (favorite: Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    var isFavorite by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(productIsFavorite) }

    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isFavorite,
        onCheckedChange = {
            isFavorite = !isFavorite
            onFavoriteClicked(isFavorite)
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            tint = color,
            modifier = modifier.graphicsLayer {
                scaleX = 1.3f
                scaleY = 1.3f
            },
            imageVector = if (isFavorite) {
                Icons.Filled.Favorite
            } else {
                Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder
            },
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }

}
```

I try use .selectable but i dont know if is that the case

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `items(productList) { CardProductItem(it) }` as your `LazyColumn`'s body?

Comment: And I still don't understand what favoriting an item has to do with filtering or the position in the list. Can you expand on that?